# Trying to get a complete set of SCOTUS opinions

Tags: software, us-supreme-court

I am trying to get a complete set of SCOTUS opinions, and have been trying to use courtlistener.com for the purpose, but the API is horrifically under-documented, and crippled. If anyone can tell me how to do this (with courtlistener or otherwise), I would appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 5):

### Supremecourt.gov

The Supreme Court has its own website, and [lists all the opinions of more recent terms there](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/slipopinion/22), and older ones [gathered in the volumes back to the 1991 term.](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/USReports.aspx)

Older cases you will need to look up at law libraries, or [Archive.org](https://archive.org/search?query=UNITED+STATES+REPORTS&sort=date&and%5B%5D=subject%3A%22microfilm%22&and%5B%5D=subject%3A%22Government+Documents%22) - while the archive isn't fully complete, there's a [ginormous collection of all the US reporters before 2008 going back to 1790, starting with Volume 1](https://archive.org/details/pub_united-states-supreme-court-cases-adjudged?sort=date). There are also similar reporters from state supreme courts, and occasionally other court reporters from pre-1790.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I will investigate.

Comment: The older reports seem to be a little sketchy (in the literal sense), and perhaps too ginormous. One might have thought that SCOTUS opinions would be of sufficient interest in and of themselves...

Comment: Life was different in 1790-1900.

Comment: It might have been, but we have had some fifty years to remedy the situation, and yet, here we are, using stone axes. Sad.

Comment: Let me tell you, those documents are in **splendid** condition and you have multiple copies of the same. That is a gorgeous situation compared to the situation when it comes to documents printed a mere 180 years before that.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but there is not a proper digital form with metadata, etc. It can be fixed with modern technology fairly easily, but it is surprising that it has not been.

Comment: Metadata take **work** to make.

Comment: It does, which is why I am asking the question, instead of just magically generating it. But I repeat, it has been fifty years since we had some sort of technology to help, and the cost of doing this is not billions. Anyway, I guess we can do it now.